# How to insert an element on the page that is at an angle in the Figma layout?

Tags: html, css, figma

In Figma, the element is given at an angle of 4.93 degrees (screenshot). The transform: rotate(-4.93deg) CSS property produces a result that looks different from the layout. How to insert this element into the page?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKu5k.png)

html:

```
<div class="tape">
    <img src="img/Frame.svg" alt="tape_at_an_angle" class="tape__img">
</div>
```

css:

```
.tape__img {
transform: rotate(-4.93deg);
```

}

Comment: Please include enough code in your question which we can run to see the problem for ourselves. 'looks different' doesn't help us know what the problem might be. (Having said that, it's possibly transform-origin). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with inserting code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've done what you asked.